# Modify Wicket's XML Resource Bundle with Java internationalization (i18n)

Tags: java, xml, internationalization, wicket

In the resource XML there are all these values associated with keys.I want to modify a value associated with a key directly from Java.

For instance,I have `<entry key="greetingMessage">Welcome to my app</entry>` and this is displayed in the view,but also the message can be modified from the view and I want to be automatically updated in the XML.

I have managed to do this by parsing and changing the XML with `javax.xml` and `org.w3c` but I feel I am missing something.Does Java internationalization or Wicket framework have a method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Wicket only has facilities to read i18n resources (for example, `XmlFilePropertiesLoader`). `Properties.storeToXML()` is not used in Wicket 6 code, while `Properties.loadFromXML()` is used to read those XML properties files.

To store those translations back to XML files you need to be cautious. At least, synchronization has to be implemented to make sure that simultaneous edits are not lost.

I'd not recommend to store the edits in XML (especially in the original XML files). It seems better to have two levels of properties:

1. First, immutable, level, is based on the original (and immutable) XML files.
2. Second level consisting of 'edits' acts like a patch over the first level. It may be stored in a database which is much more convenient for storing a constantly updating data (like such edits).

Comment: Yes,the content associated with entities is stored in a localization-structured database.But the client wants all the text to be editable.From your point of view, should I move all my text into the database and not use the  i18n resources in this case ?

Comment: What I suggested is to make all the i18n data editable, but only store the edited keys in database while taking default values from XML for keys which were not edited. This way it would be easier to just step back to 'XML only'. But your way (drop all the XML files and store everything in database) seems viable as well, it will be simpler (having only 1 layer).